# Script giving duplicate result while parsing links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an image link from a webpage using my following script but when I run it, the script fetches two links (same link twice) from there. Why am I getting such weird results?

I need to maintain the format of list comprehension as there are few pages where I can see more than one image links. However, I do not wish to use `set()` to kick out those duplicate image links either. Is there anywhere I'm going wrong while using the selector?

[Link to that webpage](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/49449866?search_identifier=2e03e08fed561a91f2bc7ed1df3f9d2b)

This is my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "check_out_the_link_above"

def get_image_links(s,link):
    s.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    images = [item.get("src") for item in soup.select("img.dp-gallery__image")]
    print(images)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        get_image_links(s,url)
```

Result I'm getting:

```
['https://lid.zoocdn.com/645/430/f8eaf79c39145242e9a30e8d550972e07c0d15a1.jpg', 'https://lid.zoocdn.com/645/430/f8eaf79c39145242e9a30e8d550972e07c0d15a1.jpg']
```

A single link twice which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two same images: first located inside `noscript` node and hidden, second is visible.

The best one would be to use XPath `//img[@class="dp-gallery__image" and not(ancestor::noscript)]`, but since bs4 doesn't support XPath, you can try CSS selector

```
ul > li > img.dp-gallery__image
```

Comment: I can't wait to accept your answer @sir Andersson. It perfectly did the job.

Comment: I suppose you missed those spaces around `"ul > li > img.dp-gallery__image"` otherwise it will produce null values.

Comment: @TOPTO , Hmm... Actually it should not affect... Probably due to specifics of bs4. OK. I've updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The source website has that image link twice, both under the same class.

```
<noscript>
    <li class="dp-gallery__list-item dp-gallery__list-item--orphan">
        <img src="https://lid.zoocdn.com/645/430/f8eaf79c39145242e9a30e8d550972e07c0d15a1.jpg" class="dp-gallery__image" alt="Swale Avenue, Peterborough, Cambridgeshire. PE4">
    </li>
</noscript>

    <li class="dp-gallery__list-item dp-gallery__list-item--orphan">
        <img src="https://lid.zoocdn.com/645/430/f8eaf79c39145242e9a30e8d550972e07c0d15a1.jpg" class="dp-gallery__image" alt="Swale Avenue, Peterborough, Cambridgeshire. PE4">
    </li>
```

If you want to avoid the second, I would add another filter to your search to make sure you only get one of them.

The simpler solution, assuming memory is not a huge issue, would be just to take images[0].